# responsive layer on layer

Tags: html, image, mobile, nested

first of all keep in mind I uderstand a very little of HTML language...
if you answer, do it as if you'd do it to a 10yo boy...
The question:
I'd like to have a background image in my website and another one on it.
the bg's image can be freely resized to match the screen or mobile size,
but the second one should keep its aspect ratio....!

http://www.flickr.com/photos/110747328@N03/
![you'll see on the left the full screen size and on the right the mobile size][1]

Comment: welcome SO. to get good answer, you should provide code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if understand you correctly. Here's what I get:
You want your bg image to be dynamically resized according to the size of the screen, but not the "content". 
You can get the first by using the "background-size: cover"'s CSS property for your background:

```
    body {
       background: url('path-to-your-image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       background-size: cover;
    }
```

After that, if you just create a div and put your content in it. You'll get what you want: for the background to be resized and the content to keep its proportions.
Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/agarridob/8NtwE/ 
By the way, I strongly recommend that you take a look at http://www.bentobox.io, where you'll find lots of resources that will help you understand a bit of what this HTML & CSS is.

Comment: Looking at the users skill level I'd suggest also adding information about prefixes etc (for cover).

Comment: @Damien, isn't background-size supported by all browsers "as it is" now?

Comment: Ah, of course you're right. Ok, IE8 then. If you care about that browser. ;)

Comment: Hi Alberto, did you take a look at my flickr link?
I knoe how to let the BG resized according to the screen size OR letting the BG being resized keeping his proportions, ratio. But not how to make it work with two different images in that two different ways. I cannot post any code because I don't know how to write the code....take a look even here: ww2.boutiquedellafotografia.it and consider I don't want a white backgrond! But an image background.